# Angularstrap datepicker not working

Tags: angularjs, requirejs, datepicker, angular-strap

I'm using AngularJS with requireJS with angularstrap. Right now I simply want to get a datepicker working in my modal box which also uses angularstrap and bootstrap but I keep recieving the error:

```
Cannot read property 'dates' of undefined
```

myctrl1.js is the file that downloads datepicker.js and I have all my dependancies in main.js listed. I have never been able to get what should be a fairly simple thing to work so posting here is my last resort.

Plunkr here: [LINK](http://plnkr.co/edit/RLi4KjwnPJQGJK5Ez4i6?p=preview)

Main files are index.html, controllers.js, myctrl.js

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when using jQueryUI. This datepicker is incompatible with jQueryUI datepicker (both use `datepicker` name), so you should remove jQueryUI from your code or do some namespace workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you forgot add [bootstrap-datepicker.js](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker) on your page. I had same problem and this was solution.

Comment: In my plunkr example I have required the plugin. This was a while ago now, I ended up just including the bootstrap date picker plugin and created my own directive. I also removed angularstrap and replaced it with angular ui as it has a phew things I don't like about it.